# Hyphens in Personal Logos

Tags: logo, critique

How do I go about incorporating a hyphen into a personal logo? I'm currently working on the initials P and C of a double barreled last name (eg. Jean-Baptiste) and I thought the hyphen of the last name would be an elegant distraction from the classic PC acronym. Here is what I have came up with so far.

[image: concept 1]

[image: concept 2]

Comment: Hi Ryan, I apologize for not looking at the guidelines. I edited my post to the best of my ability.

Comment: I'll reopen but I think it might get voted to close again. We shall see.

Comment: I think you should add some background information for why you're using the initials with the hyphen. For the first logo design, viewing without context, it looks like a logo for a eye doctor.

Comment: @AndrewH the last name legally has a hyphen in it, much like the popular French last name Jean-Baptist. Also this logo is for a freelance marketing consultant.

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked. How to use a hyphen? Isn't that they same as asking how to use *anything* in a logo? There are a million ways one could use a hyphen in a logo.

Comment: While this is a good design question, it's not a good StackExchange question. It's really a brainstorming question. I'd suggest that you grab a pencil, paper, and sketch, sketch, sketch, sketch. Then maybe post those sketches and we can better address some specific options.

Comment: @AndrewH I see opera glasses.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that for most cases a hyphen doesn't add much to a design and could be avoided to keep the logo simpler. As a personal logo, what did you intend to convey?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use it or not use it: a logo need not be so literal.

However, I notice right away that the "C" can read as a "P" with the line removed. The hyphen can act as the removed line. If you make a "C" shape and a line/rule, you can mirror and rotate these two shapes to form both letters and the hyphen. This will unify the letters better than what is shown in your samples.

Because of the simplicity, there is no reason to use a font for this particular idea.